# What are the dangers of storing plaintext data in cookies?

Tags: security, cookies, user-accounts

I see many sites that store cookie data as garbled text, for example: a cookie named `aASFaewqWDRE@fr` with an equally unreadable value. I've always kept my cookies human readable, but never keep critical data within them. For example, I'd make a cookie called `favorite_items` with a string like so `14,73,7`, each number being a reference to something like a product.

If my cookie were to be stolen, the attacker would immediately know that this user had items 14, 73, and 7 in their favorites. This doesn't compromise the users account in any way, as far as I know (assuming that my site is well built and an account can't be accessed with solely this information).

Are there other security concerns with this practice that I haven't thought of?

Comment: why not store all of that critical information in your database, and when the user logs in, just lookup the info? This way there's nothing to store in the cookie and there's no security issues.

Comment: This is probably better asked on [security.se]

Answer (score 0):

How do I really know that this is question is really from the legitimate user Brian? How do I know that it's not someone trying to trip people up? It would be in the general interest of security (for whatever reason) to encode ('garble') your data - simple because you do not know who or what is monitoring your data. Consider an account with amazon or a major retailer where a customer's credit card information is on file. If the data being monitored, it would be very simple for a potential hacker/malicious program to extract the information he needs. He can either directly get credit card details or he simply just has to acquire their username/password combination. Now when this comes to banks, it becomes extremely important.

But even outside of financial transactions, it is good to encrypt your details to prevent you from being spammed and or to prevent the illegal use of your account - imagine your boss getting an email from you with stuff that he might not like. The list is endless. The bottom line really is that there are a lot of messed up people out there and if you can do something to get that extra level of protection for not much additional cost, then why not?

Answer (score 0):

> What are the dangers of storing plaintext data in cookies?

The "danger" is obvious.  The user (and potentially others!) can read the information, and potentially "fiddle" with it.

Whether it matters depends what the information is, how you handle the cookies and what you are worried about.  For example ...

- If you are using the cookie content for implementing your site security / user access control, then passing the information it the clear could give the user extra some knowledge to subvert your scheme ... depending on how you implemented it.
- If you are using the cookie content for information that the user might consider as sensitive, then passing the "clear" cookies over an HTTP connection makes it vulnerable to some bad guy who can snoop the packets.  (Actually, given the HTTPS is "not really as secure as we were lead to believe" ... this probably applies across the board!)
- If you are using the cookies for tracking the user ... or something else that the user would probably not like you doing ... well, go figure!

But seriously, your question strongly suggests that you need to learn *a lot more* about how to address security and privacy concerns in website / webtool implementation.

For a start, simply "garbling" the information is insufficient.  Any light-weight "garbling" scheme can easily be reverse engineered.  If you care about security / privacy, the information should be encrypted using strong encryption with properly handled keys ... or not stored in cookies in the first place.  (Read up on schemes for storing session-related information on the server side.)